# Can I be sure about the parameter's SIGN if the convergence is problematic?

Tags: regression, bayesian, multilevel-analysis, autocorrelation, convergence

I fitted a large multilevel SEM model, used a 1 million iterations and 8 chains, but for some parameters the estimates still diverge across chains, and the corresponding autocorrelations are above .6 even for large lags. All PSRs are below 1.1. Although my estimates differ across chains they all have the same sign (i.e. estimates of all chains are positive). The question is:

Can I be sure that in the true model the parameter is positive, regardless of the low convergence?

I realise that low convergence might point to the fact that not all the possible parameter space has been explored and thus parameters can be in fact negative, but doesn't consistency across 8 chains and a million iterations give me some certainty at least about their sign? Or is it absolutely ungrounded claim?

[image: For instance this parameter is positive all along]

Here's a subset of the plot above. Randomly chosen, 3 chains and 1000 iterations.
[image]

Comment: Could you show trace plots and Rhat for "but for some parameters the estimates still diverge across chains"? The above trace plot seems fine to me. What software package you are using? It seems to me at least for the above parameter, you do not need 1 million iterations. To reduce autocorrelation, you may consider thin.

Comment: @TrungDung I used Mplus software and created plots manually. The above plot used thinning of 100 and it didn't help either. Do you think it's fine to have an autocorrelation of  .6 or higher? The closer look at the chains shows estimates between .8 and 1.6 for different chains, which is quite a lot substantively.

Comment: Could you show the Rhat, Effective sample size, the traceplot for just three (maybe randomly chosen) chains from eight chains to see what your problem is?

Comment: @TrungDung I've added the plot with three chains in the post. For this parameter, ESS(bulk)= 541, ESS(tail)= 962, Rhat=1.013.

Comment: ESS is large enough, for me, more than 400 for ESS, and less than 1.1 for Rhat as a good criteria for convergence.

Comment: @TrungDung thanks, this is reassuring